# SEDE query is returning error when trying to get questions with a certain score and tags

Tags: sql, dataexplorer

I am trying to search for questions on Puzzling Stack Exchange that contain certain tags so that I can find puzzles that I might be able to solve.

I have been able to write a [simple script](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/revision/1822069/2214356/) that conforms to my other restriction of having a post score of between 0 and 10, however when I try to implement the restriction of having certain tags by including an inner loop, it gives me the error

```
Line 5: Incorrect syntax near the keyword "FROM"
```

for some reason.

Here is my code that I have so far:

```
SELECT p.Title, p.Id, p.Score, p.ViewCount, u.DisplayName, q.Tags
FROM Posts q INNER JOIN PostTags pt ON q.Id=pt.PostId
INNER JOIN Tags t ON t.id = pt.TagId
WHERE t.TagName=##tagName:string?logical-deduction##
FROM Posts p
JOIN Users u ON p.OwnerUserId = u.Id
WHERE p.PostTypeId = 1
And p.Score <= 10
And p.Score >= 0
And p.AcceptedAnswerId is null
ORDER BY p.Score DESC
```

My question is: Why is this "incorrect syntax" error being caused? I feel like it may be a problem with either of the `INNER JOIN`s, but I'm not really that sure.

---

The result I would like here is for the code to return the same table of questions as I have already done, along with the added restriction of only returning questions with the `logical-deduction` tag.

I don't exactly have a lot of prior experience with SEDE/SQL, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thazt is no valid sql, the can only be one FROM and all WHEREs belomg toghter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out what my problem was:

- First off, I tried placing Line 6 (`JOIN Users u ON p.OwnerUserId = u.Id`) elsewhere, however no matter what, there would be an error caused by invalid syntax on that line. So, I decided to scrap it for now.
- In fact, when retrieving the value for `p.PostTypeId`, `WHERE` should actually be `And` because `p.PostTypeId` isn't a value that needs to be restricted. (which is also another error I encountered when fixing this)
- After that, it was a matter of needing to remove Line 5 (`FROM` should only be in the code once, as [mentioned by @nbk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78084134/sede-query-is-returning-error-when-trying-to-get-questions-with-a-certain-score#comment137657482_78084134)), and realizing that I need to put `JOIN Users u ON p.OwnerUserId = u.Id` on Line 3 because the code ends up breaking if the `JOIN` function doesn't come before the `INNER JOIN`s.

---

So, in conclusion, the reason there was an error was because my code was a dumpster fire and would probably have been fixed sooner if I had just tidied up my code a little.

---

The reworked code:

```
SELECT p.Title, p.Id, p.Score, p.ViewCount, u.DisplayName, p.Tags
FROM Posts p
JOIN Users u ON p.OwnerUserId = u.Id
INNER JOIN PostTags pt ON p.Id=pt.PostId
INNER JOIN Tags t ON t.Id = pt.TagId
WHERE t.TagName=##tagName:string?logical-deduction##
And p.PostTypeId = 1
And p.Score <=10
And p.Score >=0
And p.AcceptedAnswerId is null
ORDER BY p.Score DESC
```

Comment: I think you might want the joins against `PostTags` and `Tags` as an `EXISTS`